# SELECT FOR JSON outputs exponent on floating points

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

When I execute the following query:

```
DECLARE @KG FLOAT = 5.0;

WITH Weight(KG, LB) AS (SELECT @KG, @KG * 2.2046226218)
SELECT * FROM Weight;
```

I get this output:

```
| KG | LB           |
|----|--------------|
| 5  | 11.023113109 |
```

Now when I simply append `FOR JSON AUTO` to output JSON,

```
DECLARE @KG FLOAT = 5.0;
    
WITH Weight(KG, LB) AS (SELECT @KG, @KG * 2.2046226218)
SELECT * FROM Weight FOR JSON AUTO;
```

I get the following output:

```
[{"KG":5.000000000000000e+000,"LB":1.102311310900000e+001}]
```

I know this the above is valid JSON, but my desired output is:

```
[{"KG":5,"LB":11.023113109}]
```

**Important note:** I realize that I can get the desired output by simply declaring `@KG` as `DECIMAL` or `INT`. I'd rather not do that, since I'm selecting from a `VIEW` that I do not have permissions to edit, and I don't want to individually cast each `FLOAT` column to `DECIMAL` if possible.

Is there a way to do this without casting each individual value to `DECIMAL`?

Comment: Cant you declare KG as int?

Comment: Again, not really. Both `KG`, `LB`, and several other columns in the `VIEW` I'm selecting from are all `FLOAT`. I really do appreciate the thought, though. My best option is still to cast. The query in the question is just a very simple way to reproduce the problem. I just edited the original question.

Comment: Than I think cast is only way

Comment: Well, that's what I'm afraid of. There are just a lot of columns, and I would prefer to simply `SELECT * FROM MyView FOR JSON AUTO` rather than `SELECT CAST(KG AS DECIMAL) KG, CAST(LB AS DECIMAL) LB, [etc ...] FROM MyView FOR JSON AUTO`

Comment: Can't you create a wrapper view and cast the columns there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`exact numeric datatypes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql):

```
DECLARE @KG DECIMAL(38,12) = 5.0;

WITH Weight(KG, LB) AS (SELECT @KG, @KG * 2.2046226218)
SELECT * FROM Weight FOR JSON AUTO;
```

**[DbFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d2e8304866fc43f98ea4e5488f13948c)**